# MySQL SQLSTATE [2002] Connection refused on a ubuntu 20.04LTS LAMP server

Tags: mysql, linux, lamp

I need someone to tell me how to create the appropriate user to be able to connect to mysql.
I have a file called db.inc which is located in the includes directory/folder.

```
<?php
  $dbuser = "user1";
  $dbpwd = "password";
  try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=domain.com;dbname=domain', $dbuser, $dbpwd);
  }
  catch( PDOException $Exception) {
    $exccode = $Exception->getCode();
    $excmsg = $Exception->getMessage();
  }
  if (!empty($exccode)) {
    die($exccode." - ".$excmsg."<br>\n");
  }
?>
```

I have also run the following SQL command:

```
# mysql
mysql> CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user1'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> exit
```

Currently I am getting the error "2002 - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" and I am unable to figure out why I am getting this error.

Can someone explain what needs to be done to make this work?

I know this is a small issue for someone who works with LAMP servers and MySQL every day.

Comment: Your host should be localhost assuming you did not open the remote connections for the mysql.

Comment: I do not understand? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Is your mysql running locally on the same machine and listening on default port 3306? you did not specify port in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Your host should be localhost if you are running the code and the database in the same server.

```
<?php
  $dbuser = "user1";
  $dbpwd = "password";
  try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=domain', $dbuser, $dbpwd);
  }
```